# rake db:create throwing LoadError: cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I am totally new to ruby and currently setup a framework which was written in ruby.

While configuring it starts failing when I launch the below command

rake db:create

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_support/security_utils
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/actionpack-4.1.15/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/actionpack-4.1.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:228:in `<class:Base>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/actionpack-4.1.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:164:in `<module:ActionController>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/actionpack-4.1.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/gon-5.2.3/lib/gon/helpers.rb:59:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/gon-5.2.3/lib/gon.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/open-source-billing/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/open-source-billing/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/open-source-billing/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

While running the command rake db: create getting below error

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a DB gem like SQLite3 or PostGreSQL installed?

Comment: can you paste content of your `config/database.yml` file ?

Comment: did you `bundle install` first?